# Selenium Firefox starts, but does not open any URL

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the python version of selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\%user%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\fyet0w0h.default")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
browser.get("https://helloworld.com/")
```

firefox driver open, but i can't load any url with browser.get("url"). No proxy. Python 3.2 Firefox 31

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably wrong selenium version / firefox version combination

Comment: Does it work without passing in a Firefox profile?

Comment: Also, if you set up logging, do you see any errors there? https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DeveloperTips#Getting_output_from_the_error_console_to_a_file

Comment: This is really too vague to be answered as is. We need more details from you, either the stack trace, the error message, or something similar. This is most likely a configuration problem and without those, any potential solutions are just speculation. My initial guess is it's a version of firefox not compatible with the version of selenium you're using because that is perhaps the most common problem I see for these sort of issues.

Answer (score -1):

WebDriver supports the following browsers and operating systems:

- Google Chrome 12.0.712.0+
- Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8, 9, 32-bit and 64-bit versions
- Firefox 3.0, 3.5, 3.6, 4.0, 5.0, 6, 7, 8, 9
- Opera 11.5+
- HtmlUnit 2.9
- Android - 2.3+ for phones and tablets (devices and emulators)
- iOS 3+ for phones (devices and emulators) and 3.2 + for tablets (devices and emulators)

I download FF 9.0.1 and ..it worked

Answer (score -1):

Downgrading to FF 9 is not a solution. Because FF will get automatically upgraded and the applications need to be tested in upgraded version. What if the requirement is only to test on FF 25- FF 27? 
We have to check why the url was not loading.
First try downloading the latest jar of Selenium standalone webdriver.
please check if your windows is a 64 bit or 32 bit machine
download the jar according to that.

Comment: I'm not use FF every day, and download and install FF 31 for me is .. first experience in use FF in this year :) And downgrading to FF 9, for me is solution

Answer (score -1):

Needs to upgrade the selenium, If you are using Latest version of Firefox, you should use latest version of selenium

For Python, Enter this command

```
pip install -U selenium
```

For Java, Remove the old jar and Download Latest Version from here http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and Attach into build path. It will work find . Happy Testing with Firefox